# App doesn't have network connection

Tags: ios, cordova

My iOS build of my app does not seem to want to connect to the internet at all. Can someone point me in the right direction with this?

I've added the address that I am trying to connect to, to the white list. Though I am not sure where to start with this as this is my first iOS app. I'm not sure if there is an error generated some where that I'm not seeing.

The app builds fine and is pushed to both the Simulator and a physical iPhone. It works on the Simulator. The iPhone has a connection and can browse the web so I know that is not the issue.

Let me know what else you may need to help with this as I'm not sure what I need to provide.

**Edit**

Below script logs the user into the system using a backbone.js model which sends an ajax request to the server. This works fine on the Android Build.

```
App.user = new App.model.user({
    'email'     : $(event.currentTarget).find('#email').val(),
    'password'  : $(event.currentTarget).find('#password').val()
});
```

The user model:

```
App.model.user = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults    : {
        "email"         : null,
        "password"      : null,
    },
    initialize  : function () {
        this.save(null, {
            success : function (model, response) {
                App.loggedIn = true;
                App.navigate("menu", {
                    trigger : true,
                    replace : true
                });
                App.menu();
            },
            error   : function (model, response) {
                try {
                    App.mainView.error(response.resultMessage);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            },
            wait    : true
        });
    },
    urlRoot     : App.config.siteUrl + "/gateway/user"
});
```

Comment: There's a whitelist? As for a starting point, put breakpoints where-ever you're instantiating network requests / receiving results / errors and see what's going on...

Comment: Posting the code you are using might help. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm just sending an Ajax request using the Backbone.js to a service. Will add the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following.

1) Have a dummy html page

```
< html>
 < head>
  < script>
      window.location.href="Your absolute URL you are trying to reach"
  < /script>
 < /head>
 < body>Loading< /body>
< /html>
```

If that does not work, set whitelist to * and try again. If it works something wrong in the way whitelist is set

2) See if you are accessing a secure URL. If it works on simulator and doesn't work on phone, see if the phone has access to the URL you are trying to hit. Try using mobile safari.

3) Make sure you are using right cordova file. (The cordova.js is different between Android and IOS)

4) If mobile safari is able to connect, they try using the webview debugger as specified in [this awesome post](http://atnan.com/blog/2011/11/17/enabling-remote-debugging-via-private-apis-in-mobile-safari/)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Looks like iOS doesn't like going to HTTPS sites that do not have a valid SSL Cert.

Comment: Glad to be. Yeah, I saw this behavior with secure sites in my phonegap applications..

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to fix you `Cordova.plist` :

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: What do you mean by fix `Cordova.plist`? I already have the site added in the whitelist as outlined in the documentation you have linked to.